# Finding the probability of a poker hand with two hearts and at least one spade.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to find the probability of a poker hand with two hearts and at least one spade. I have the following result:

$$\frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{1}\binom{26}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}} + \frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{2}\binom{26}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}} + \frac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}} = \frac{6539}{33320} \approx 19.62\%$$

Did I go about it the right way? I tried to use some of the concepts I learned on Khan Academy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  That'll do.

Alternatively: $\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\left(\binom{39}3-\binom{26}3\right)}{\binom{52}5}$

Comment: Thank you for the alternative!